# Url of Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have many url in my index.phtml, but when i try to use them i still in the home page !!
i have tried to use many functions basepath(), url() but i have the same problem.
this is my controller:

```
class VehiculesController extends AbstractActionController
 {
/**
 * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
 */
protected $_objectManager;
protected function getObjectManager()
{
if (!$this->_objectManager) {
$this->_objectManager=$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
}

return $this->_objectManager;
}

public function indexAction()
{
$vehicules = $this->getObjectManager()->getRepository('Vehicules\Entity\Vehicule')     
->findAll();
    return new ViewModel(array('vehicules' => $vehicules));
}
 public function VehLibreAction()
{
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTemplate('Vehicules/Vehicules/VehLibre');
    return $view;
}

public function VehReserveAction()
{
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTemplate('Vehicules/Vehicules/VehReserves');
    return $view;
}
public function VehIndisponibleAction()
{
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTemplate('Vehicules/Vehicules/VehIndisponible');
    return $view;
}
public function VehHorServicAction()
{
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTemplate('Vehicules/Vehicules/VehHorServic');
    return $view;
}
}
```

and this is my index.phtm

```
    <div>
    <div>
    <div>
    <div>
    <h3>liste des véhicules</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
    <div> <a href="<?php echo $this->url('vehicules', array('action'=>'VehLibre'));?  >">   liste des Vehicules libres</a></div>
    <div><a href="<?php echo $this->basePath("vehicules/vehicules/VehLibre"); ?>">liste des    Vehicules reservés</a></div>
    <div><a href="<?php echo $this->url('vehicules', array('action'=>'VehIndisponible'));?  >">liste des Vehicules indisponibles</a></div>
    <div><a href="<?php echo $this->url(NULL,    array('controller'=>'vehicules','action'=>'VehHorServic'));?>">liste des Vehicules hors   service</a></div>

                <?php if (isset($vehicules)) : ?>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th>Marque</th>
                        <th>Matricule</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                <?php foreach($vehicules as $v): ?>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $v->getIdveh(); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $v->getMatricule(); ?></td>

                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </table>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All the urls are routes in your app? Are the routes defined already?

Comment: Show us your app routes configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The urls -

`<?php echo $this->url('vehicules/default', array('controller'=>'vehicules', 'action'=>'VehLibre')); ?>` 

and 

`<?php echo $this->url('vehicules/default', array('controller'=>'vehicules', 'action'=>'VehIndisponible'));?  >` 

will work by setting the routes in `module.config.php` as:

`'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'vehicules' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/vehicules',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Vehicules\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'Vehicules',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    ...
),`

This should work now.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have added those lignes but the browser didn't found the page !!

Comment: I have update the answer. Just try the `$this->url([...]` code from it.

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly, please i want to know what was the problem !!

Comment: The structure says that there are 2 routes defined (parent and child - i.e. `vehicules` and `default` respectively). Then 2 variables - `:controller` and `:action`. So while creating the `$this->url([...])`, you have to mention the route name as `vehicules/default` and pass the `controller` and `action` values in the array.

Comment: but in some exemples they mention just the module's name or null instead  and the url works ?!! it depends on module.config.php ??

Answer (score 0):

This is my module.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Vehicules\Controller\Vehicules' => 'Vehicules\Controller\VehiculesController',
                'Vehicules\Controller\option' => 'Vehicules\Controller\optionController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'vehicules' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    // Change this to something specific to your module
                    'route'    => '/vehicules',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        // Change this value to reflect the namespace in which
                        // the controllers for your module are found
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Vehicules\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Vehicules',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    // This route is a sane default when developing a module;
                    // as you solidify the routes for your module, however,
                    // you may want to remove it and replace it with more
                    // specific routes.
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'Vehicules' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
        'doctrine' => array(
                'driver' => array(
                        'Vehicules_driver' => array(
                                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                                'cache' => 'array',
                                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Vehicules/Entity')
                        ),
                        'orm_default' => array(
                                'drivers' => array(
                                        'Vehicules\Entity' => 'Vehicules_driver'
                                )
                        )
                )

        )
);
```